# Best way to go about reading a website?

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to create a program that grabs data from a website x amount of times and I'm looking for a way to go about doing so without huge delays in the process.

Currently I use the following code, and it's rather slow (even though it is only grabbing 4 peoples' names, I'm expecting to do about 100 at a time):

```
$skills = array(
    "overall", "attack", "defense", "strength", "constitution", "ranged",
    "prayer", "magic", "cooking", "woodcutting", "fletching", "fishing",
    "firemaking", "crafting", "smithing", "mining", "herblore", "agility",
    "thieving", "slayer", "farming", "runecrafting", "hunter", "construction",
    "summoning", "dungeoneering"
);

$participants = array("Zezima", "Allar", "Foot", "Arma150", "Green098", "Skiller 703", "Quuxx");//explode("\r\n", $_POST['names']);

$skill = isset($_GET['skill']) ? array_search($skills, $_GET['skill']) : 0;

display($participants, $skills, array_search($_GET['skill'], $skills));

function getAllStats($participants) {
    $stats = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($participants); $i++) {
        $stats[] = getStats($participants[$i]);
    }
    return $stats;
}

function display($participants, $skills, $stat) {
    $all = getAllStats($participants);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($participants); $i++) {
        $rank = getSkillData($all[$i], 0, $stat);
        $level = getSkillData($all[$i], 1, $stat);
        $experience = getSkillData($all[$i], 3, $stat);
    }
}

function getStats($username) {
    $curl = curl_init("http://hiscore.runescape.com/index_lite.ws?player=" . $username);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, sprintf("Mozilla/%d.0", rand(4, 5)));
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, (int) $header);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $output = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close ($curl);
    if (strstr($output, "<html><head><title>")) {
        return false;
    }
    return $output;
}

function getSkillData($stats, $row, $skill) {
    $stats = explode("\n", $stats);
    $levels = explode(",", $stats[$skill]);
    return $levels[$row];
}
```

When I benchmarked this it took about 5 seconds, which isn't *too* bad, but imagine if I was doing this 93 more times.  I understand it won't be instant, but I'd like to shoot for under 30 seconds.  I know it's possible because I've seen websites which do something similar and they act within a 30 second time period.

I've read about using caching the data but that won't work because, simply, it will be old.  I'm using a database (further on, I haven't gotten to that part yet) to store old data and retrieve new data which will be real time (what you see below).

Is there a way to achieve doing something like this without massive delays (and possibly overloading the server I am reading from)?

P.S: The website I am reading from is just text, it doesn't have any HTML to parse, which **should** reduce the loading time.  Here's an example of what a page looks like (they're all the same, just different numbers):
`69,2496,1285458634 10982,99,33055154 6608,99,30955066 6978,99,40342518 12092,99,36496288 13247,99,21606979 2812,99,13977759 926,99,36988378 415,99,153324269 329,99,59553081 472,99,40595060 2703,99,28297122 281,99,36937100 1017,99,19418910 276,99,27539259 792,99,34289312 3040,99,16675156 82,99,39712827 80,99,104504543 2386,99,21236188 655,99,28714439 852,99,30069730 29,99,200000000 3366,99,15332729 2216,99,15836767 154,120,200000000 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 30086,2183 54640,1225 89164,1028 123432,1455 -1,-1 -1,-1`

My previous benchmark with this method vs. `curl_multi_exec`:

```
function getTime() { 
    $timer = explode(' ', microtime()); 
    $timer = $timer[1] + $timer[0]; 
    return $timer; 
}

function benchmarkFunctions() {
    $start = getTime();
    old_f();
    $end = getTime();
    echo 'function old_f() took ' . round($end - $start, 4) . ' seconds to complete<br><br>';
    $startt = getTime();
    new_f();
    $endd = getTime();
    echo 'function new_f() took ' . round($endd - $startt, 4) . ' seconds to complete';
}

function old_f() {
    $test = array("A E T", "Ts Danne", "Funkymunky11", "Fast993", "Fast99Three", "Jeba", "Quuxx");
    getAllStats($test);
}

function new_f() {
    $test = array("A E T", "Ts Danne", "Funkymunky11", "Fast993", "Fast99Three", "Jeba", "Quuxx");
    $curl_arr = array();
    $master = curl_multi_init();

    $amt = count($test);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $amt; $i++) {
        $curl_arr[$i] = curl_init('http://hiscore.runescape.com/index_lite.ws?player=' . $test[$i]);
        curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_multi_add_handle($master, $curl_arr[$i]);
    }

    do {
        curl_multi_exec($master, $running);
    } while ($running > 0);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $amt; $i++) {
        $results = curl_exec($curl_arr[$i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This page was implemented strictly for reading purposes for developing applications, they are fine with it.

Comment: Your point?  Nothing in there says anything about accessing their website for information.

Comment: @Ron You recently accepted an answer that is not PHP native.  I have posted one that you might want to consider for quick, PHP implementation.

Comment: @Dagon Why is that any of your concern? He asked a question regarding his code - not legal advice advice...

Comment: @Ron I'd like to help you turn this into a class, if you'd like me to.  It really should be, I feel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can reuse curl connections.**  Also, I changed your code to check the `httpCode` instead of using `strstr`.  Should be quicker.

Also, you can setup curl to do it in parallel, which I've never tried.  See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php

**An improved `getStats()` with reused curl handle.**

```
function getStats(&$curl,$username) {
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://hiscore.runescape.com/index_lite.ws?player=" . $username);
    $output = curl_exec($curl);
    if (curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)!='200') {
        return null;
    }
    return $output;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$participants = array("Zezima", "Allar", "Foot", "Arma150", "Green098", "Skiller 703", "Quuxx");

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); //dangerous! will wait indefinitely
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, sprintf("Mozilla/%d.0", rand(4, 5)));
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
//try:
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Connection: Keep-Alive',
    'Keep-Alive: 300'
));


header('Content-type:text/plain');
foreach($participants as &$user) {
    $stats =  getStats($curl, $user);
    if($stats!==null) {
        echo $stats."\r\n";
    }
}

curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: I didn't know about `curl_multi_exec`, it does look promising.

Comment: @NateC-K I'd like to see a quality example of comparable code and then the speed tests.  It could be VERY promising.

Comment: I remember benchmarking `curl_multi_exec` versus my example and it was slower almost every time.  Maybe I was doing it wrong?  I've added what I did to the main post, if you could look at it I'd be grateful.

Comment: @Ron Try implementing my curl reuse and compare times.  Be sure to make sure the comparison is fair.

Comment: The result of that was: function old_f() [your implementation] took 4.7657 seconds to complete<br>function new_f() [original new_f()] took 5.547 seconds to complete<br>function old_ff() [original old_f()] took 10.6492 seconds to complete, so I guess you're correct!  Would you suggest using `curl_multi_exec` in a different manner?

Comment: @Ron I haven't ever used the curl_mutli_exec, I just know it exists.  Maybe tomorrow I'll look into it.

Comment: Thank you, I'll vote this as correct for now, seeing as it's faster and is along the lines of what I am looking for.

Comment: @Ron I've added an option for the HTTP header keep alive.  Test that out to see if it makes a difference.  It might be on be default, but it doesn't hurt to check.

Comment: It doesn't seem to have changed drastically, it's only about a 300ms difference.

Comment: @Ron Try it on a significantly larger array of users and then compare, unless your website won't ever have a larger set of users.

Comment: I did it with 55 different names and the benchmark results were `23.4901 milliseconds without keep-alive` and `14.3921 milliseconds with keep-alive` so it seems keep-alive is the way to go!

Comment: @Ron I'm glad I could help.  I mentioned up above that I'd like to help you write this into a class instead of using just functions.  Is that something you'd like?

Comment: I would greatly appreciate that!  Would you need the whole file?  If so I can upload it to a pastebin site for you.

Answer (score 2):

When you are doing a bunch of network requests like this, you are at the mercy of the network and the remote server regarding how much time they take to respond.

Because of this, the best way to make all of your requests complete in the shortest amount of time is probably to do them all at once. Spawn a new thread for each one. For the size of the data you're working with it's probably quite possible to do literally all at once, but if that's a problem then maybe try 20 or so at once.

EDIT: I just realized you're using PHP which doesn't have threads. Well, probably a poor choice of language, for starters. But you might be able to emulate threads by forking new processes. This might be a wreck, though, if PHP is running inside the web server process, since it would clone the whole server. I'll look into whether PHP offers some sort of asynchronous web requests that could give a similar effect.

EDIT 2:

Here is a page discussing how to launch an HTTP request in the background with PHP:

http://w-shadow.com/blog/2007/10/16/how-to-run-a-php-script-in-the-background/

However, this is "fire and forget," it doesn't let you pick up the response to your request and do something with it. One approach you could take with this, though, would be to use this method fire off many requests to a different page on your own server, and have each one of those pages make a single request to the remote server. (Or, each worker request could process a batch of requests if you don't want to put start too many requests at once.)

You would still need a way to assemble all the results, and a way to detect when the whole procedure is complete so you can display the results. I would probably use either the database or the filesystem to coordinate between the different processes.

(Again, choosing a more powerful language for this task would probably be helpful. In the realm of languages similar to PHP, I know Perl would handle this problem very easily with "use threads", and I imagine Python or Ruby would as well.)

EDIT 3:

Another solution, this one using the UNIX shell to get around PHP's limitations by doing the work in separate processes. You can do a command something like this:

```
echo '$urlList' | xargs -P 10 -r -n1 wget
```

You would probably want to play with the `wget` options a bit, such as specifying the output file explicitly, but this is the generally idea. In place of wget you could also use `curl`, or even just call a PHP script that's designed to be run from the command line if you want complete control over the job of fetching the pages.

Again, with this solution you still have the problem of recognizing when the job is done so you can show the results.

I got this idea for this approach from this page:

http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3269/parallel-file-downloading-with-wget

Comment: How could I do it that way?  Last time I looked around and benchmarked this vs. that this one came out on top 8/10 times, but I assume I just did it incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you very much, would I be able to use Perl/Ruby/Python if I enabled the environments?  I've only used them in coordination with Java so I'm not sure if they work for web developing too.

Comment: In a Linux hosting environment, Perl is usually the easiest to get working because just about all UNIX-like systems have it installed by default. Assuming they have a way for you to enable CGI, that is. This really depends on your host. If you run the server yourself then you can use just about any language for web development. If you're using Apache then you will find lots of documentation online about how to do this.

Comment: I'm using a free hosting site at the moment (which I assume accounts for part of the slow speed) but I can enable processes and environments (such as cURL and PHP), do you think it'd work?

Comment: Depends on the host. Some are very restrictive, some flexible, I imagine some will give you just about anything you ask for software-wise if you call and ask nicely. The main problem I usually have with hosting is that they like to run CentOS which has very old versions of everything.

Comment: @Ron I'd like to help you build a class to do this stuff instead of just using a bunch of functions.  Is that something you'd like?

Comment: That would be amazing :)  I'm new to the whole PHP thing, and planned on doing that, but when I tried it no good came from it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are making multiple requests to the same host, you can re-use the curl handle and if the site supports keep-alive requests, it could speed up your process a good bit over many requests.

You can change your function like this:

```
function getStats($username) {
    static $curl = null;

    if ($curl == null) {
        $curl = curl_init();
    }

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://hiscore.runescape.com/index_lite.ws?player=" . $username);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Keep-Alive'));

    //...

    // remove curl_close($curl)
}
```

Doing this will make it so you don't have to close and re-establish the socket for every user request.  It will use the same connection for all the requests.

Comment: Wouldn't I need to close `curl` after I'm done processing all of the requests, though?

Comment: When the script ends, PHP will effectively clean it up for you and close its connections.  The only reason you may want to call it was if you wanted to make sure you close the socket, or the script was going to continue processing for some time and you wanted to free resources.

Comment: I don't receive a response from the server when I don't close my connection, and if I keep it there after adding `static $curl = null` and your if statement I receive `Warning: curl_setopt(): 2 is not a valid cURL handle resource in /home/aeterna/www/t/index.php on line 50`.  I replaced `$ch` with `$curl` as well.

Comment: Edited my post: Sorry I used `$ch` in the setopt call instead of `$curl`

Comment: This example doesn't seem to have sped it up any, slowed it down if anything.  :(

Comment: Using static variables in functions seems like a bad way to go. . .

Comment: I saw a good improvement, but I had to add `curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Keep-Alive'));`  Why would a static variable be a bad way to go?

Comment: The reason is that if you really need a static variable in a function, you should probably be using a class.

Answer (score 0):

`curl` is a very good way to read the content of the website - I suppose your problem is because of the time require to download **ONE** page. If you can get all the 100 pages in parallel then you would probably have it all processed in under 10 seconds.

In order to avoid working with threads, locks, semaphores, and all the challenging stuff on threads, read [this article](http://teddziuba.com/2011/02/stupid-unix-tricks-workflow-control-with-gnu-make.html) and find out a way to make your application parallel almost for free.

Comment: How could I do it that way?  Last time I looked around and benchmarked this vs. that this one came out on top 8/10 times, but I assume I just did it incorrectly.

Comment: I don't entirely understand it, how could I use `curl` in the syntax provided?

Comment: The question isn't actually using the `curl` UNIX tool, it's using the curl extension to PHP. If you were going to use the command line (using the `exec` command, I think) then you could use the parallel feature of `xargs` which is a heck of a lot simpler than the Makefile trickery you link to here. This page has an example: http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3269/parallel-file-downloading-with-wget