# How to use cURL to find subdomains containing specific strings?

Tags: php, html, string, loops, curl

I am trying to build a list of all the city pages on *ghix.com*, which does not have such a complete directory. To do this I am using their 'city id' which is unique for each city, but does not follow any particular order.

I am using cURL and PHP to loop through the possible domains to search for those that match actual cities. Simple enough. See the code bellow, which produces a *500 Internal Service Error*.

If it worked, output should be a list of 'city ids' which do not match actual cities. If the URL matches an actual city it will not have (0) on the page, but if it does not match a city it will have (0) on the page.

I have looked over and corrected this several times, what is causing the error?

```
<html>
<?php
for ($i = 1; ; $i <= 1000000; $i++) {
  $url = "http://www.ghix.com/goto/dynamic/city?CityID=" . $i;
  $term="(0)";
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, trim($url));
  $html = curl_exec($ch);
  if ($html !== FALSE && stristr($html, $term) !== FALSE) { // Found!
    echo $i;
    Echo "br/";
  } 
}
?>
</html>
```

UPDATE
a slightly different approach I tried, with the same effect...

```
<html>
<?php

for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
$url = "http://www.ghix.com/goto/dynamic/city?CityID=" . $i;
$term="(0)";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, trim($url));
$html = curl_exec($ch);
if (strpos($ch,$term)) {
    echo $url;
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you show your error log?

Comment: Your code does not do nearly what your after, for starters you have to use `curl_setopt()` to set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `true` if you want the data to be stored in `$html`. But this is not the cause of your `500` issue. Try to remove all PHP code and run the HTML, chances are the `500` issue will persist. You might have a faulty `.htaccess` or something similar.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656721/best-way-to-go-about-reading-a-website for information on proper usage of cURL and quering the same host for multiple pages.

Answer (score 8):

In your first chunk of code, you have an extra `;` in the `for` conditions.  Next, you need to initialize cURL with `$ch = curl_init();` around the beginning.  That opens the handler `$ch` that you call on later.  Finally, use `1=` for the false condition for `if` instead of the exclamation and double equal.  After these fixes, I'm not getting any 500 errors.  After that, it's just a matter of collecting the data from the pages and putting it in the right places.

In the second chunk of code, you still need to initialize cURL.  Then you need to put in another curly bracket at the end to close out the `for` loop.  And then it's a matter of dealing with the output from cURL.

It seems you are getting more typo errors than anything.  Watch your server logs and they will tell you more about what you are looking for.  And for cURL, read up on the options that you can set in PHP on [the PHP site](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).  It's a good read.  Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

What I have found is that you can use the auto-complete JSON request to find all the city ids. 
The JSON request url is `http://www.ghix.com/goto/dynamic/suggest?InputVarName=q&q=FRAGMENT&Type=json&SkipPrerequisites=1`. Here FRAGMENT is the letters you type in the input box. Iteratively request on that URL would reveal all the CityIDs you are looking for.

Be aware, they may have bot protection for such ajax queries.

I saw their JSON is malformed. It can be fixed using [`Services_JSON`](http://pear.php.net/package/Services_JSON) pear package.

```
require_once 'Services/JSON.php';
$Services_JSON = new Services_JSON();
$json = $Services_JSON->decode($jsons);
```

Using [dxtool/WebGet](https://github.com/shiplu/dxtool/blob/master/WebGet.php) the following code seems to be working.

```
require_once("WebGet.php");

// common headers to make this request more real.
$headers = array(
    "Accept-Charset" => "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
    "Accept-Encoding" => "gzip, deflate",
    "Accept-Language" => "en-us,en;q=0.5",
    "Connection" => "keep-alive",
    "Referer" => "http://www.ghix.com/goto/dynamic/search",
    "User-Agent" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Ubuntu; X11; Linux x86_64; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1"
);

$w = new WebGet();
$w->cookieFile = dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookie.txt";

// do a page landing
$w->requestContent("http://www.ghix.com/goto/dynamic/search", array(), array(), $headers);

$city_ids = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 1000; $i++) {
    $url = "http://www.ghix.com/goto/dynamic/city?CityID=" . $i;
    $term = "> (0)<";
    $w->requestContent($url, array(), array(), $headers);
    // sleep some times to make it more like request from human
    usleep(10000);
    if (strpos($w->cachedContent, $term) !== FALSE){
        $city_ids[]  = $i;
        echo $url, PHP_EOL;
    }
}

print_r($city_ids);
```

Comment: That URL is an impartial list of CityIds. For example, it does not include the city of Mably, France (CityID: 141806)

Comment: You can always simulate auto complete ajax request to get city IDs. See the update in answer.